# How to set link to a chapter or page in an rst document?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am able to set a clickable link to a local pdf document using

```
:download:`Name of book <filename.pdf>`
```

I'd like to directly link to a chapter or page, using

```
:download:`Name of book <filename.pdf#Chapter2>`
:download:`Name of book <filename.pdf#page=10>`
```

as described [here](http://www.backslash.ch/blog/2006/12/4/Auf-Seiten-im-PDF-direkt-verlinken) for internet links.

Can I make this work for local pdf file links?